# Torch: How to shuffle a tensor by its rows?

Tags: lua, pytorch, permutation, torch

I am currently working in torch to implement a random shuffle (on the rows, the first dimension in this case) on some input data. I am new to torch, so I have some troubles figuring out how permutation works..

The following is supposed to shuffle the data:

```
if argshuffle then 
    local perm = torch.randperm(sids:size(1)):long()
    print("\n\n\nSize of X and y before")
    print(X:view(-1, 1000, 128):size())
    print(y:size())
    print(sids:size())
    print("\nPerm size is: ")
    print(perm:size())
    X = X:view(-1, 1000, 128)[{{perm},{},{}}]
    y = y[{{perm},{}}]
    print(sids[{{1}, {}}])
    sids = sids[{{perm},{}}]
    print(sids[{{1}, {}}])
    print(X:size())
    print(y:size())
    print(sids:size())
    os.exit(69)
end
```

This prints out

```
Size of X and y before 
99 
1000
128
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]

99 
1
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]

99 
1
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]

Perm size is: 
99 
[torch.LongStorage of size 1]
5
[torch.LongStorage of size 1x1]
5
[torch.LongStorage of size 1x1]


99 
1000
128
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]

99 
1
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]

99 
1
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]
```

Out of the value, I can imply that the function did not shuffle the data. How can I make it shuffle correctly, and what is the common solution in lua/torch?

Answer (score 43):

I also faced a similar issue. In the documentation, there is no shuffle function for tensors (there are for [dataset loaders](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)). I found a workaround to the problem using `torch.randperm`.

```
>>> a=torch.rand(3,5)
>>> print(a)
tensor([[0.4896, 0.3708, 0.2183, 0.8157, 0.7861],
        [0.0845, 0.7596, 0.5231, 0.4861, 0.9237],
        [0.4496, 0.5980, 0.7473, 0.2005, 0.8990]])
>>> # Row shuffling
... 
>>> a=a[torch.randperm(a.size()[0])]
>>> print(a)
tensor([[0.4496, 0.5980, 0.7473, 0.2005, 0.8990],
        [0.0845, 0.7596, 0.5231, 0.4861, 0.9237],
        [0.4896, 0.3708, 0.2183, 0.8157, 0.7861]])
>>> # column shuffling
... 
>>> a=a[:,torch.randperm(a.size()[1])]
>>> print(a)
tensor([[0.2005, 0.7473, 0.5980, 0.8990, 0.4496],
        [0.4861, 0.5231, 0.7596, 0.9237, 0.0845],
        [0.8157, 0.2183, 0.3708, 0.7861, 0.4896]])
```

I hope it answers the question!

Answer (score 6):

```py
dim = 0
idx = torch.randperm(t.shape[dim])

t_shuffled = t[idx]
```

If your tensor is e.g. of shape CxNxF (channels by rows by features), then you can shuffle along the second dimension like so:

```py
dim=1
idx = torch.randperm(t.shape[dim])

t_shuffled = t[:,idx]
```

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward solution is to use permutation matrices (those that are usual in linear algebra). Since you seem to be interested in the 3d case, we will have to flatten your 3d tensor first. So, here's an example code (ready-to use) that I came up with

```
data=torch.floor(torch.rand(5,3,2)*100):float()
reordered_data=data:view(5,-1)

perm=torch.randperm(5);
perm_rep=torch.repeatTensor(perm,5,1):transpose(1,2)

indexes=torch.range(1,5);
indexes_rep=torch.repeatTensor(indexes,5,1)

permutation_matrix=indexes_rep:eq(perm_rep):float()
permuted=permutation_matrix*reordered_data

print("perm")
print(perm)
print("before permutation")
print(data)
print("after permutation")
print(permuted:view(5,3,2))
```

As you will see from one execution, it reorders the tensor `data` according to the row indexes given in `perm`.

Comment: Can you give some comments in your code as to what each statement is doing. I am trying to implement the same in numpy and I don't have background in pytorch.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your syntax, I assume you're using to torch with lua rather than PyTorch.
[torch.Tensor.index](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md) is your function, it works like below:

```
x = torch.rand(4, 4)
p = torch.randperm(4)
print(x)
print(p)
print(x:index(1,p:long())
```